# R - Progressively adding scatterplots onto the same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given dataframe `df`

```
Date        A      B      C      D      E
<POSIXct>   <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
2019-10-3   2      1      0      4      6
2019-10-4   1      0      3      3      5
2019-10-5   0      1      1      2      3
2019-10-6   6      5      2      2      6
2019-10-7   3      5      4      1      4
```

I would want to make scatterplots with regression lines of A against Date, B against Date, and so on progressively.

First plot has only A against Date, second plot has A against Date and B against Date, third plot has A against Date, B against Date and C against Date, ...

One way to plot all scatterplots into the same graph is by converting `df` to long format

Long format:

```
Date        variable  value
<POSIXct>   <fctr>    <int>
2019-10-03  A         2     
2019-10-04  A         1     
2019-10-05  A         0     
2019-10-06  A         6     
2019-10-07  A         3     
2019-10-03  B         1     
2019-10-04  B         0     
2019-10-05  B         1     
2019-10-06  B         5     
2019-10-07  B         5  ...
```

Attempt shown below:

```
# Initialize data
df <- data.frame(
        Date=as.POSIXct(c("2019-10-3", "2019-10-4", "2019-10-5", "2019-10-6", "2019-10-7"), 
        format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                      A=as.integer(c(2, 1, 0, 6, 3)),
                      B=as.integer(c(1, 0, 1, 5, 5)),
                      C=as.integer(c(0, 3, 1, 2, 4)),
                      D=as.integer(c(4, 3, 2, 2, 1)),
                      E=as.integer(c(6, 5, 3, 6, 4)) )

# Pipeline to plotting all at once
df %>% reshape2::melt(id="Date") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=value, colour=variable)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=False)
```

[image: Plotting all at once]

However, I would want to be able to add each scatterplot one by one progressively, not just all at once.

Comment: `gganimate::transition_reveal(variable)`?

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for? Five plots? One animate plot? Something else?

Comment: Yes 5 plots. Not animate. Ideally scalable to n plots if given n non-date columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach, `accumulate()` to create a filter list ( `c("A"), c("A", "B"), ..., c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")` ) which is used to generate a list of plots. It scales (constant indexes are only used for final output), though for a high number of observations and/or variables it may become bit slow.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Date, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") 

p_lst <- accumulate(names(df)[-1], c) |> 
         map(\(x) df_long |> 
               filter(variable %in% x) |> 
               ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=value, colour=variable)) + 
               geom_point() + 
               geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE) +
               theme(legend.position = "none")
             )

p_lst[[5]] <- p_lst[[5]] + theme(legend.position = "right")
p_lst[[6]] <- patchwork::guide_area()
patchwork::wrap_plots(p_lst, ncol = 3, guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Example data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Date=as.POSIXct(c("2019-10-3", "2019-10-4", "2019-10-5", "2019-10-6", "2019-10-7"), 
                  format="%Y-%m-%d"),
  A=as.integer(c(2, 1, 0, 6, 3)),
  B=as.integer(c(1, 0, 1, 5, 5)),
  C=as.integer(c(0, 3, 1, 2, 4)),
  D=as.integer(c(4, 3, 2, 2, 1)),
  E=as.integer(c(6, 5, 3, 6, 4)) )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>